# How do I communicate between a WPF and ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have a WPF application that I want users to be able to deploy to a web server so that they can view updates from it via their web browser.

I plan on building an ASP.NET solution of some sort and I want it to communicate with the running WPF application and fetch real time data from it so that it can be served via IIS to the user.

Can my WPF application send over objects to the ASP.NET application in real time? If so how? Which technology should I be looking at?

Comment: yes. it is possible to communicate between 2 apps. Why would users be able to deploy your app to a webserver ? That is confusing.

Comment: Users don't want it to run on their desktops, they need it on the cloud for some use cases. And I need to provide a basic UI for those cases. How can the WPF app push objects to the ASP.NET app? Other than using shared XML files or a shared database.

Comment: you can have some rest api endpoint in your web app to which WPF can send data.

Answer (score 1):

> Can my WPF application send over objects to the ASP.NET application in real time?

Yes

> Which technology should I be looking at?

There are a lot of technologies that you can use. Since you are using only .NET technologies, I would go with Windows Communication Foundation.

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf).

Also, you can create a RESTful service. In this case, one alternative is [WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

Yes WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) is the key. But there are several strategies..

**(1)** One solution would be to use *RSS feeds* to get the data into the ASP.NET application: upload RSS feed content from your WPF app using WCP client. This should connect to a WCF service which creates the RSS feed. There is a WCF project template for an RSS feed server in Studio 2017 named "syndication service library". You will need an RSS client module on the ASP side and let client subscribe to the RSS feed to report new data.

**(2)** *Messaging* is also an option: I'd prefer a WCF+WebSocket to stream data in real time to ASP clients.

Suppose you have some kind of  messages (e.g. serialized objects) that your WPF app users generate. The WPF app could use a WCF client, to connect to a WCF service which queues the data for publishing a WebSocket, or several Websockets.

Your web page connects to the WebSocket, which will continually provide it with new data. The interface can be implemented in a view, in JavaScript, using the WebSocket to get the data.

If you want to do more with the data e,g, on the controller level, the controller can open a WCF client to query for updates directly (poll) and real time update the html-client using Ajax, perform database updates, etc.

**(3)** An alternative setup you could consider, is *Kafka messaging*. All input by the WPF users will be persistent in Kafka and secured in a failover cluster.. and clients can poll Kafka for new messages. The WPF application will push new data in a Kafka topic, the ASP application could use Ajax or other pulling strategy to get new Kafka stuff to the web page client. NOTE: I've not yet tested the Confluent Kafka C# client in an ASP.NET context.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a Web API rather than WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) since a Web API is easy to use. You can fire `POST, GET` requests to a Web API controller using `HTTP` requests directly.

So you can make WPF application and web application use the same Web API.

Comment: Only http. And I'd say WebAPI+WebSocket for pushing messages to the client. ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Socket.

Copy and paste on the MVC application.

NOTE: use your own IP address and port

```
public static void SendNotification()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    try
    {
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
        IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 59313);

        using (Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test from web application<EOF>");

                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

copy and paste in WPF application

```
public static void Receive_notofication()
{
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
    IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 59313);

    try
    {
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);

        Thread wpfThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Create and start the WPF application on a new thread
            var app = new Application();
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow(); // Replace 'MainWindow' with your actual WPF window class
            app.Run(mainWindow);
        });

        wpfThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        wpfThread.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();

            string data = string.Empty;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            // Wait until a message is received from the client
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                if (data.Contains("<EOF>"))
                {
                    data = data.Replace("<EOF>", "");
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Process the received message in the WPF application
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                // Use the 'data' variable as needed in the WPF application
                MessageBox.Show(data);
            });

            byte[] response = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            handler.Send(response);
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```